# Passing a boolean between different objects not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I know this has been covered in the past, but I believe this issue is being caused by the update to Unity 5, thus deprecating the older information. No errors come up, but the debug won't come up. The public variable of 'pushBlockEnter' does become true visibly on the player script, but the pushBlock class will not recognize it no matter what. I just want to be able to check if a variable is true in one script from another script in Unity 5, any way of doing it would be fine. I'm sure it is something simple but I just can't figure it out...I should also mention that both scripts are on a different object. Thanks in advance!:

```
public class pushBlock : MonoBehaviour {
public Player playerScript;

void Update () {

    if (GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>().pushBlockEnter)

    {
    Debug.Log ("do something blahh");
    //Do Anything
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I also tried this, and it doesn't work either, before anyone mentions it:
if (gameObject.GetComponent<name of the script holding the bool>().IsLightOn)//will check if true

Comment: Is `pushBlockEnter` declared as `public static`?

Comment: You really should not be using `.Find()` every frame, as it is an expensive function to call.  You should be assigning it to that variable you have and referencing it that way.

Comment: Do you have anything in console?

Comment: Nothing in the console, no.

Comment: Draco, I know it is just one line to call a component and a variable to assign it to another variable like you said, but I figured that would be a whole other question. Do you know off hand?

Comment: Because it isn't: 
 PBEnter = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>().pushBlockEnter

Comment: And it isn't: Player.GetComponent.< Player >().pushBlockEnter = false;

Comment: Is the checkbox for `Push Block Enter` checked off when viewing the script in the Unity editor? How are you ascertaining that `pushBlockEnter` is true?

Comment: By looking at it in the inspector, it is a public variable. And in response to Claudiu, no it is not static, why?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
GameObject playerReference = GameObject.Find("Player");

void Update(){
    if (GameObject.Find("pushBlockCollider").GetComponent<pushBlockCollider>().inPushBlock){

        Debug.Log ("got to pushblockCollider True");

}
```